# strapi v4 with postgres error, database does not exist

Tags: strapi

I have tried to install the latest strapi version with the following command:

```
npx create-strapi-app@latest strapi_test
```

After going through the manual steps and choosing postgres as my db, from within my folder I run the `yarn develop` command, but then I get the following error:

> debug: ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
>
> error: database "strapi_test" does not exist

[image]

[image]

What have I done wrong?
I am running node v16.13.0, npm v8.2.0 and on Mac OS Monterey v12.2.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Had the same problem, turns out you need to create the database yourself with psql. So you need to run:

`psql -U postgres`

`create database strapi_test;`

It should work correctly after this.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) 
I couldn't use the pql -U postgres command, as I was getting "role "postgres" does not exist" but with the command psql postgres I could create the database and then run the yarn develop command. 
Thanks once again, saved me a ton of headache :)

Comment: these commands are not working for me. I have installed Postgres, but when executing these commands, I get the following message in the terminal: `'psql' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to what @Unbound said above:

What's missing from the equation, after installing PostegreSQL, is the psql command not being available globally. So what you have to do, is define the directory in the PATH variable globally. I had to look through the folders, to find the correct location of the executable, but in the end I ran this command (PostgreSQL 15):

```
export PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/15/bin:$PATH
```

After running this command, psql worked wonders everywhere. You might have to start new terminal session as well - to see it work.